# Most efficient way to know if a database table has been updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, database

I am wondering what is the most efficient way to know if a db table has been updated? I am using Codeigniter as the framework. 
So far the method I have considered is to use a timer and make an ajax post request to the backend every 15-20 seconds. However, if a page is left idle, wouldn't that just slow down the site?
Is there another method to do this or is this the only way.

Comment: the terminology is not clear, `efficient` in terms of actuality (real-time) / resources e.g. cpu / bandwidth ?

Comment: if you just need it every 15-20 sec... the post request should be fine enough...

Comment: Sorry, efficient as in resources for the end user. If the site keeps making requests, would the page slow down eventually?

Comment: a request every 15-20 sec, is not critical, if you are working with PHP, you could also consider to use long-polling, instead of ping - requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several techniques for this.

Yes, you could poll regularly to check for any update dates on your database, but several other solutions aim to provide more consistent, push-driven, reactive update detections.

For Javascript, I can think of MeteorJS: https://www.meteor.com/

MongoDB offers oplog tailing features, to monitor database operations in realtime: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/tailing-mongodb-oplog-sharded-clusters but this requires a sharded cluster.

Some other DB engines might provide features to stay updated on tables, lines or documents. For example take a look at RethinkDB (real time web) : https://www.rethinkdb.com

Another way to deal with updates is to use messaging (such as with nodejs/websockets or RabbitMQ, Kafka...) so you can inform your clients of any updates performed by connected back-end services.

Actually, ideal database update detection is a little bit hard to implement and requires technology choices.

You will have to decide if you wish to sacrifice performance over the altar of complexity. If you expect many users to do a lot of polling for many things, you might want to organize your project around a more consistent architecture.

Comment: Thanks for answering! What I've found is that Innodb has a function that checks if a table has been modified recently. I would use another framework if I could. Maybe the next version. I guess for now constant polling would be the only way.